# How to extract the largest sequence of the same character in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

There might be different approaches but the prompt was to fill a row of seats for example

```
----------
```

so that each seat is the farthest away from the other seat so

```
-----X---
```

and for the next one

```
--X--X---
```

so on and so forth

Here's my code so far:

```java
public static void occupyOneMore(char[] anArray) {

    //initialize and declare variables
    int longestStart = 0;
    int longestSeats = 0;
    int currentSeats = 1;
    int currentStart = 0;
    char emptySeat = '-';

    //scan every element
    for (int index=1; index < anArray.length ; index++) {
        System.out.print(" index " + index);
        //System.out.print(" checking - index is " + index);
        if (anArray[index] == emptySeat && anArray[index] == anArray[index-1]) {
            currentSeats ++;
        }
        //  currentStart = index - currentSeats;
        else if (currentSeats > longestSeats){
            longestSeats = currentSeats;
            longestStart = currentStart;
            System.out.println("Else statement");
        }
        //System.out.print( " current seats - " + currentSeats);
    }
    System.out.println(longestSeats);
    System.out.println(longestStart);

    int mid = (longestStart + (longestSeats+longestStart)) / 2;
    anArray[mid] = 'X';
    System.out.print(anArray);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the connection with the title and the question. Please be clear about what your actual problem.

Comment: I would start seating from an end